# Can we Use Multiple Database in a same Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, phpmyadmin

Can we Use phpmyadmin and Firestore in a same Android App ?? Assuming if one part of the App contain a realtime feature (Chatting App),for which Database is Firestore And other part contain simple user features like viewing the stored data in Database(eg. Wikipedia),lets say it's DB is PhpMyadmin. will it be posssible ?

Comment: Yes you can use it.

Comment: Ashish sir, how ?

Comment: You can find that on google about retrofit and firebase

Comment: Sir I'm very new to Android & firestore . And Im a final year MCA student So I'm planning my last semester project like this way but I can't find any idea how to Implement it. Can you give me some source from where I can learn it ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking about using the phpMyAdmin application alongside these other tools, but phpMyAdmin has a mobile interface that you can use to perform many of the administrative tasks from. Entering complex SQL queries isn't much fun on a mobile device, but the phpMyAdmin interface scales reasonably well to a smaller screen.

Comment: Isaac ,  I asked about phpmyadmin because my project guide want admin panel in web not through the app. That's the reason, as I didn't find any other way And I didn't know much.So I planning on making the admin panel using php .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. I did that recently in a project. Firebase is very easy just check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs).

You can actually use Firebase for everything. including storing and retrieving data. but, if you want to use another online DB, Web server or API that's totally doable.

I would recommend that you do a separate demo project using firebase and another Retrofit for example.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Remon, but I want my Admin panel access from web not through this app. All the Admin data must be inserted through web coz it's easier for a admin to insert or update anything. what should I do Can you give me some suggestion

Comment: Firebase works for web too, but I have never done any web before. but you can use the same firebase database for both web and android app

Comment: Yeah I know it but I tried several tutorial to connect to it,It show many difficulties.And I thing instead of php we have to use javaScripts for the web part ,if we do so.

Comment: like I said I don't know about the web part. but IMO try to have only once source for data whenever possible.

Comment: @DipankarDutta if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.